# Cypress giving false positive and not failing test despite finding wrong text

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cypress

As mentioned in the title, the cypress client proceeds on to other tests without marking a test as failed where it has in fact found a mismatch in the expectation. This behavior can be seen in the attached image:

[image]

This is intermittent but can go completely unnoticed when the tests run in a CI environment.

How am I supposed to debug & fix this issue?

Comment: Perhaps you can report it to Cypress GitHub issue page. I rocommend attaching more information, ideally a reproducible example.

Comment: The problem is that it does not happen consistently. So without changing my code it will work as expected and sometime as shown in the question.

Comment: It looks like an intermittent bug. But a bug anyway.

Comment: Can you add the code for the assertion ?

Comment: Just because the error is intermittent doesn't mean it's not a bug in your code. Regardless of whether it's a fault of Cypress or your code, we'd need a [mcve] for this to be actionable.